# How to Detect All Redundant Typing (Diamond Operators) With Regex?

Tags: java, regex

I use Intellij IDEA for my Java projects. I want to upgrade my code from Java 6 to Java 7 style (I will not support Java 6 anymore). I want to start with "only" removing redundant typing operators. I know that Intellij shows it if there is a diamond operator but how can I get the list of them?

i.e.

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

will be:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
```

**PS:** Something as like that may work:

Not start with start character because it is a comment line, at least one character, and start with "<" character and end with ">" that includes some characters inside, arbitrary characters, "=" character, nothing or whitespace character,  start with "<" character and end with ">" that includes some characters inside?

Comment: What is an example of a redundant diamond operator?  Also, the diamond operator isn't allowed in Java 6, so if you're upgrading, surely you don't have any yet?

Comment: Did you mean, redundant type args that can be replaced with the diamond operator?

Comment: Maybe a regex search that is: not start with start character because it is a comment line and start with "<" character and end with ">" character two times?

Comment: Perhaps simply search for all occurences of `>();`?

Comment: Uh, IDEA has builtin code inspections detecting this...

Comment: @fge yes but the code is so huge. I want to find and replace them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why you want a regex, anyway, IDEA has this inspection builtin, at least with 13.x.

File -> Settings, select "Inspections".

There is a search bar: in it, type "diam"; it will show an inspection "Java language level migration aids" -> "Explicit type can be replaced with <>": if it is not selected, select it.

Then, after selecting the correct JVM for your project, "Analyze" -> "Inspect code": this will list all occurrences of all inspections; select the inspection above: you then have the option to apply this correction to all occurrences.